# np.load for several files

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

It is needed to load several files with `.npy` extension and write content from it to a new array.

Why that code doesn't work? What should I improve?

```
A = np.empty(0)
for file in files:
    inf_from_every_file = np.load(file)
    A = np.append(A, inf_from_every_file)
```

Comment: What is the content of `files` and what is the error that you are getting? Also, if you have multiple files with contents that you want to concatenate into one big array you may find better performance appending each loaded array into a list and then concatenating them all with [`np.concatenate`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.11.0/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html).

Comment: Use of `np.append` in a loop like this is slow, and it is hard to get the right starting value.  `np.empty(0)` is not the equivalent a list `[]`.  Stick with the list append approach, and deal with joining those arrays into one after the loop.

Answer (score 1):

As has been pointed out in the comments, *it is not clear what you mean by "doesn't work"*. Given that `files` contains file names or paths of the form (`'a_file.npy'`) and given that these files actually exist *in the current working directory or in the given paths*, your code should "work".

However, your code as it is will `flatten` the loaded arrays and append them together into one big 1D array. This is most likely not what you want, so I will assume that this is your problem.

To solve this problem with your approach, you would have to look at the `axis` keyword for `np.append`.

However, appending to numpy arrays in a loop is generally a bad idea, since a complete copy of the array is created during each `append`. Therefore, you should either stick with a list followed by `np.concatenate`:

```
A = []
for fname in files:
    inf_from_every_file = np.load(fname)
    A.append(inf_from_every_file)
A = np.concatenate(A)
```

...or you should initialize the entire empty array from the start and then add values to it by indexing:

```
A = np.empty( (len(files),) + np.load(files[0]).shape )
for index,fname in enumerate(files):
    A[index,...] = np.load(fname)
```

Note that the line initializing `A` gets a bit complicated if you don't know the shape of the arrays that should be loaded. Here, I am loading the first array from the list to get the shape information. If you already know that the shape is e.g. `(100,100)`, you can instead use

```
A = np.empty( (len(files), 100, 100) )
```